# Getting lost with JS Sum of odd Numbers?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting stuck with an exercise on codewars and I need some guidance.
this is the a exercise Given the triangle of consecutive odd numbers:

```
             1
          3     5
       7     9    11
   13    15    17    19
21    23    25    27    29
...
```

Calculate the row sums of this triangle from the row index (starting at index 1) e.g.

And this is my code :

```
function rowSumOddNumbers(n) { 
  let sum = 1; 
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2*(n-1); i++){ 
    sum+= i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a bit more specification, like "the result of index X should be Y"? The current code seems to sum up the whole triangle up to a certain point instead of only a single row?

Comment: Yes sure, exemple : rowSumOddNumbers(1); // 1 = 8 rowSumOddNumbers(2); // 3 + 5 = 8, .... etc

Comment: `rowSumOddNumbers(3) === 8` and `rowSumOddNumbers(4/5/6) === 27` and `rowSumOddNumbers(7/8/9/10) === 64`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt at solving the problem:

```
function rowSumOddNumbers(n){
    let amountOfNumbers = 0;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++){
        amountOfNumbers +=i;
    }

    let sum = 0;
    for (j=1; j < amountOfNumbers; j+=2){
        sum += j;
    }

    return sum;

}
```

First, I create a for loop to count the amount of numbers that the pyramid will have. Then, I add the numbers to the final sum.

Please add any edits to the function if it needs to be improved.